# Ajax call to report parent of popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page on this address: http://www.example.com/landingpage/

Some sites are using JS to pop up my page over theirs and I need to know if there is a way to implement a JS code in http://www.example.com/landingpage/ that will tell me where the page was popped up from (is it considered to be the parent window?)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [window.opener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.opener) to obtain a reference to the owner window if your document is loaded in a popup:

```
if (window.opener) {
    // We're in a popup window, do something.
}
```

That said, [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) will prevent you to interact with the owner window if its document was served from another domain (or using a different protocol).

Also, the above doesn't take `<iframe>` elements into account. If you want a more bulletproof solution, you can do something like:

```
if (window !== window.top || window.opener) {
     // We're not the top frame or we're in a popup window, do something.
}
```

Comment: So I can tell when the page is popped up, but I cannot know where it was popped up from?

Comment: is there any other way of knowing where my page was popped up from?

Comment: I'm afraid not. Same origin policy is quite strict (for good reasons), and existing workarounds such as [HTML5's postMessage()](http://ajaxian.com/archives/using-html-5-postmessage) require cooperation from code in both documents.